# General expression for creating an equal length lag dataframe

Tags: r

I have a vector and run the following autocorrelation function where I obtain the significant lags and create a dataframe adjusted to the minimun length of the lags. The example produces random numbers and thus it maybe necessary to repeat the code so enough lagged variables occur.

```
   L library(quantmod)

x <- filter(rnorm(100), filter=rep(1,3), circular=TRUE)   

a<-acf(x)
b<-a[[1]]   
c<-(b[2:length(b)])
posssignificance_level<-qnorm((1+0.95)/2)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(x)))
negsignificance_level<- -posssignificance_level
poscorr<-which(posssignificance_level<c)
negcorr<-which(negsignificance_level>c)
L<-(sort(c(poscorr,negcorr)))

#[1] 1  2  8  9 10


#Create lagged versions of x 
W1 <- na.omit (Lag(x, L[1]))
W2 <- na.omit (Lag(x, L[2]))
W3 <- na.omit (Lag(x, L[3]))
W4 <- na.omit (Lag(x, L[4]))
W5 <- na.omit (Lag(x, L[5]))


#make all laged versions equal in length 
shortest <-min(length(W1),length(W2),length(W3),length(W4),length(W5))
W1<-tail(W1, shortest)
W2<-tail(W2, shortest)
W3<-tail(W3, shortest)
W4<-tail(W4, shortest)
W5<-tail(W5, shortest)

#create data frame
df<-data.frame(W1,W2,W3,W4,W5)
```

Is there a more efficient and maybe a general way to do #Create lagged versions of x and  #make all laged versions equal in length as to create a dataframe provided that if x numbers are changed the length of L may also change (the number of objects (W1,W2...) may also change)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you're doing without needing to know the length of `L`.  In your example all the lagged versions are equal in length (100 observations), but this should work if they are not:

```
# create lagged version
Wlist <- lapply(seq_along(L), function(ii) na.omit(Lag(x, L[ii])))
# find shortest
shortest <- Reduce(min, lapply(Wlist, function(x) length(x)))
# create data frame and make all lagged versions equal in length
data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(Wlist, tail, shortest)))
```